# show JSON data(from php file) in table using ajax

Tags: php, json

I hava a php code as shown below **serverdata.php**

```
<?php

require_once('database.php');
header("Content-type: application/json");  

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$uid = array();
$uname = array();


while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
   {
     $dataarray[] = $row;
   }

  echo json_encode($dataarray); 
?>
```

which produce the following output in JSON format:

```
[{"id":"1","username":"Sagun","password":"61b51ae250c7e7505191e4d5e6240c04"},{"id":"2","username":"roshan","password":"d6dfb33a2052663df81c35e5496b3b1b"},{"id":"17","username":"rajiv","password":"9a9af43c15771eaf3b2db8bb28a2829d"}]
```

All i want is to get the data from above php file that is in json format and display it in table in another page using AJAX. Please guide me through it.

```
 ID USERNAME PASSOWRD 
  1   sagun   61b51...    
  2   roshan  d6dfb.. 
 17   rajiv   9a9af..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**database.php**

```
    <?php
try{
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testing', "root" , "");


}catch(PDOException $e){
    print "error in connection" . $e->getMessage();
}
```

**home.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>JSON data</title>
</head>
<body>

  <table id="demoTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td ><label>Id</label></td>
        <td ><label>Username</label></td>
        <td ><label>Password</label></td>
      </tr>
    </thead> 
    <tbody>  
    </tbody>  
  </table>
  <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="detail.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**details.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url:'serverdata.php',
        type:'POST',
        success:function(data){

            var result = $.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(result, function(key, value){
                $.each(value, function(k, v){
                    if(k === "id"){
                        $("#demoTable >tbody:last").append(
                            $('<tr>').append(
                                $('<td>').append(v)
                                .append(
                                    $('</td>').append(
                                        $('</tr>')
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            );
                    }
                    if(k === "username"){
                        $("#demoTable >tbody >tr:last").append(

                            $('<td>').append(v)
                            .append(
                                $('</td>')

                                )

                            );
                    }
                    if(k === "password"){
                        $("#demoTable >tbody >tr:last").append(

                            $('<td>').append(v)
                            .append(
                                $('</td>')

                                )

                            );
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    })      
});
```

**serverdata.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'database.php';
$data = array();
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM user');
$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key] = $value;
    $result = json_encode($data);
}
echo $result;
```

Comment: tried so many tutorial, m not getting it
 `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="details.js"></script>
    <body>
        
     <table>
         <thead><tr>
                 <th>ID</th>
                 <th>Username</th>
                 <th>password</th>
         </tr></thead>
         <tbody id="mytable">
             <tr>
                 <td id="userid"></td>
                 <td id="username"></td>
                 <td id="password"></td>
             </tr>
         </tbody>
     </table>`

Comment: see my updates and try again .. hope it will help you

Comment: your code works great when i use json file.. but not working when i use php file. here is the php file if any thing i need to change ?  `<?php
header("Content-type: application/json");   require('database.php');


$sql = "SELECT * FROM user";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$uid = array();
$uname = array();


while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
   {
     $dataarray[] = $row;
   }
   
  echo json_encode($dataarray); 
  
 ?> `

Comment: it means...now you want to retrieve data in json format.. is it??

Comment: that above php code generate data in JSON format, [["1","Sagun","61b51ae250c7e7505191e4d5e6240c04"],....... cant we use that php file ??  i dont want to save it in JSON file. retrive it only

Comment: use this code as **serverdata.php**  `<?php 
$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "your username"; 
$pass = "your password"; 
$database = "your database"; 

$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Could not connect to host."); 
mysql_select_db($database, $conn) or die("Could not find database."); 

$stmt = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user");
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
   $rows[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
?>`

Comment: wiil you plz send me all file.. at dropbox

Comment: why are you using **mysql_connect** instead of **PDO**  ?

Comment: i have done in PDO also but its same not working, check it out https://www.dropbox.com/s/wdkd7gpr9ekj5nd/phpjson.zip?dl=0

Comment: i have update my answer and it is now fully working .you can copy these codes or downlod file from link https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vd872i039dyqow0/AADibZ1SJ-Rs_Gk0wpb0VhsCa?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

This is the ajax function to get your json data from php output, try to modify as you need.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type      : 'POST',
        url       : 'YOUR_PHP_URL',
        data      : {},
        dataType  : 'json',
        error     : function (a, b, c) 
        {

        },
        success   : function(data) 
        {
            console.log( data );
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Don't forget to include the jQuery library.
https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery

Answer (score 1):

This code for build table in jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function jsonData()
{

    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:"serverdata.php",
        datatype:'json',
        success:function(data)
        {
            var jdata=$.parseJSON(data);
            ///console.log(jdata);
            $(function(){
                $.each(jdata,function(i,item){
                    var tr = $('<tr>').append(
                    $('<td>').text(item.id),
                    $('<td>').text(item.name),
                    $('<td>').text(item.email),
                    //$('<td>').text(item.password),
                    $('<td>').text(item.mob_num),

                );
                $("#tableId tbody").append(tr); 
                //console.log(tr.wrap('<p>').html());
                })
            })

        }
    })
}
```

Comment: could not get any data i don't know what is problem. :(

Comment: please give your script